# Review test with irrelevant tag

Tags: discussion, tags, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I was reviewing the low quality posts with my interested topics filtered.
The queue was finished, then there appeared another task to review when I refreshed the page.

The question was about JavaScript which is not in my filtered topics.
I checked out the original post to see which topic was matching.
CMake was in the tags.
I was going to remove the irrelevant tag from the question right after completing the review.

The post to review was written in a well-mannered format with a suggestion to use another JS package.
While I am not expert on the topic, it seemed to me that it was a good enough post. So, I chose *This post looks OK*.

Suddenly, *STOP! Look and Listen.* title popped up and I lost the previous version of the post.
The irrelevant tag has never existed since the question is not modified.
What is more interesting is that the deleted question was removed by community bot with no proper explanation where the deleted answer is similar to an existing one.

I copied the [link to the removed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73909456/12447766) but I can no longer access it.
The original post is here: [Find JavaScript Code Integrate Clarifai Face Detection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567960/find-javascript-code-integrate-clarifai-face-detection-api)

My questions are as following.

1. Is the close decision really accurate? Some explanation would be nice.
2. Is the filtering algorithm faulty? I should not have faced with such a post in the first place.
3. I was banned previously because of an awareness test in a different queue. Although this test result says there is nothing to worry about, considering the weirdness of the situation, can a similar test result in suspension of my ability to review?
4. Shouldn't I be able to access the deleted answer at least for a while?

Comment: *"The question was about JavaScript which is not in my filtered topics"* This is an *immediate* indicator that the review is an audit.

Comment: an important part of reviewing is understanding how to circumvent the audit system

Comment: 1. The *answer* was marked as Spam, and the account has been deleted. I suspect the user made multiple posts to advertise the same product(s). 2 See prior comment. 3. Failing multiple audits can result in a review queue ban, yes. 4. Viewing deleting post is a 10k+ privilege, having reviewed that post (as an audit) doesn't change that.

Comment: The review task is here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33044406 - I think you can see it here since you're the reviewer.

Comment: As for this, it's a bad audit.  With the context you had available, you wouldn't be able to tell it was spam.

Comment: You haven't failed any other audits recently, so you're not suspended from review for this, but if you're suspended for entirely bad audits, you can always flag one of your own posts for moderator attention to get unsuspended...with the caveat that the flag backlog is really large right now and we _might_ not spot it before the suspension ends.

Comment: [More about audits...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)